# How to properly use returned value from delayed gulp task in another one

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

A simple example: I have 2 gulp task (second requires valued from the first one), but cannot get value in second one set right (during first task execution using setTimeout):

```
var gulp = require("gulp");

var values = undefined;

gulp.task("one", function(cb) {
    console.log(values);
    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log('First finnished!!!');
        values = "Vovan and Alex";
    }, 1000);
    cb(values);
})

gulp.task("two", ["one"], function() {
    console.log(values);
    console.log("Second's done!")

})

gulp.task("default", ["one", "two"]);
```

Resulting in following:

`[18:24:26] Using gulpfile ~/workspace/gulpfile.js
    [18:24:26] Starting 'one'...
     undefined
    [18:24:26] Finished 'one' after 1.58 ms
    [18:24:26] Starting 'two'...
    undefined
    Second's done!
    [18:24:26] Finished 'two' after 302 μs
    [18:24:26] Starting 'default'...
    [18:24:26] Finished 'default' after 17 μs
    First finnished!!!`

Answer (score 0):

You're telling gulp that your task finished by calling `cb`, which happens too soon in your example. If you move the `cb` call to within the timeout, it will wait for the task to finish:

```
var gulp = require("gulp");

var values = undefined;

gulp.task("one", function(cb) {
    console.log(values);
    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log('First finnished!!!');
        values = "Vovan and Alex";
        cb(values);
    }, 1000);
})

gulp.task("two", ["one"], function() {
    console.log(values);
    console.log("Second's done!")

})

gulp.task("default", ["one", "two"]);
```

However, you're calling `cb` with an array of strings and gulp requires a stream of some sort. You could write the value to a shared variable or create a stream with your data to pass between tasks.

Comment: well.. it breaks with error ` [18:43:58] 'one' errored after 1 s
[18:43:58] Error: Vovan and Alex `

Comment: That's because gulp expects a stream and you're passing an array of strings. I mentioned that at the end of the answer.

Comment: You'll need to instantiate a stream of some sort, with the appropriate data, and return that.

Comment: @ssube He doesn't need a stream. The problem is that you are still passing an argument to the `cb` callback. That tells gulp that an error has occurred. Use `cb()` instead of `cb(values)`.